# Expressing $e^{2\pi ix}$ in the basis of kernels of $Df = f(x+1) - f(x)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, functional-equations

Let $Df$ be an operator such that $Df = f(x+1) - f(x)$

Observe that

$$ D(e^{2\pi ix} ) = e^{2\pi i(x+1)} - e^{2 \pi i x} = 0$$

So if we attempt to place it in the basis $(1,x, \frac{1}{2}x(x-1), \frac{1}{3!}x(x-1)(x-2) ... )$

We naively assume that

$$ e^{2\pi i x} =  e^{2\pi i (0)} + D(e^{2\pi i x})[0] x + \frac{1}{2}D^2 (e^{2\pi i x} )[0]x(x-1) +  ...$$

But this tells us

$$ e^{2\pi i x} = 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 ... $$

Which has me very confused. How do I find cofficients $c_0, c_1 ... $ such that

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k \begin{pmatrix} x \\ k  \end{pmatrix}  = e^{2\pi i x} $$

If the operator falls through, does this mean its EVEN possible?

Comment: The standard Taylor series (of say $e^{-1/x^2}{\bf 1}_{x>0} = 0 + 0 + \ldots $) does not have to converge to the function it's approximating. Neither does the finite difference analouge which is what you have here. btw this expansion is often called [Newton's interpolation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Newton.27s_series)

Comment: See also this MO question [Discrete-analytic functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71206/discrete-analytic-functions) for which the accepted answer has some nice references for which functions that can be expanded this way.